# How to create .exe file with cx_Freeze along with third party python packages?

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I am new to python programming and I want to create an .exe file along with third party python packages. My requirements is that if I give the source code of the project to any developer, he/she will simply run `python setup.py build` so that .exe file will be created. I have mentioned also `install_requires` in the `setup.py` file by mentioning the third party packages, but I am getting the errors. I provide below the code. This requirement is similar to java, maven based application where user runs the pom.xml to create the executable.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includefiles = []
includes = []
excludes = ['Tkinter']
packages = ['configparser == 4.0.2', 'colorama == 0.4.3', 'xlsxwriter == 1.2.7']
build_exe_options = {'includes':includes,'packages':packages, 'excludes':excludes, 'include_files':includefiles}

base = None

setup(name = 'Testing',
        version = '0.1',
        author = 'DD Mishra',
        description = 'A simple application',
        install_requires = ['configparser == 4.0.2', 'colorama == 0.4.3', 'xlsxwriter == 1.2.7'],
        options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable('main.py', base=base)]
)
```

I am using the command `python setup.py build`. First of all I want to install all the required packages like **configparser**, **colorama**, **xlsxwriter** and after that the exe should be created. All should happen automatically without manually installing the packages using `pip` command.

As per my above setup while running the command `python setup.py build`, I am getting the following error.

> running build running build_exe Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "setup.py", line 13, in 
>       setup(name = 'Testing',   File "C:\devsoftwares\Python38\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line
>   340, in setup
>       distutils.core.setup(**attrs)   File "C:\devsoftwares\Python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
>       dist.run_commands()   File "C:\devsoftwares\Python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in
>   run_commands
>       self.run_command(cmd)   File "C:\devsoftwares\Python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in
>   run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()   File "C:\devsoftwares\Python38\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135,
>   in run
>       self.run_command(cmd_name)   File "C:\devsoftwares\Python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in
>   run_command
>       self.distribution.run_command(command)   File "C:\devsoftwares\Python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in
>   run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()   File "C:\devsoftwares\Python38\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line
>   211, in run
>       freezer.Freeze()   File "C:\devsoftwares\Python38\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py",
>   line 610, in Freeze
>       self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()   File "C:\devsoftwares\Python38\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py",
>   line 354, in _GetModuleFinder
>       finder.IncludeModule(name)   File "C:\devsoftwares\Python38\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line
>   631, in IncludeModule
>       module = self._ImportModule(name, deferredImports,   File "C:\devsoftwares\Python38\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line
>   348, in _ImportModule
>       raise ImportError("No module named %r" % name) ImportError: No module named 'configparser == 4.

0.2'

Answer (score 0):

## PRE

I have a bad news for you.
Although the setuptools works like you & I & maybe lots of others would think. The setuptools works perfectly what you're trying to achieve with those nifty dependencies. I'm currently trying to achieve the same as you.
https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html?highlight=pip%20install%20requirements#setup-cfg-only-projects (using only cfg instead of the setup.py script). Still trying. Sooo keep updated, I'll do the same here.
BUT, as you guess, this lib is not bringing here the same philosophy.

## The root-cause (not the reason of WHY)

My 'workaround' which is silly and not really a workaround but a way to see what is the philosophy behind, but what you did there was checking in debug mode, and you won't believe, I found out that in your example the

```
build_exe_options = {'packages':packages}
```

are being imported by several steps: taking the Python default packages, if not: trying to import from the ACTUAL PYTHONPATH (or PATH) environment variable. LOL. I see the root-cause, not yet the WHY.

## Possible solution (as a workaround)

So what everyone stepping in the same rabbit-hole, avoid it by not specifying the packages' version, only their name. If those dependencies listed are not installed, you'll be surprised: the same fail will happen...

We can clearly see, that this option's intention was NOT the same, as the *install_requires* from **setuptools**, and we can clearly see, that without that option highly doubtedly won't 'copy-paste' the dependencies, cuz' that's what it does.